# Perl regular expression not matching

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following regular expression in Perl.

```
if ($line =~ m/DX/o) {
  printf("%s.\n", $line);
}

if ($line =~ m/.*DX\s+.*\s+.*\s+(.*)\sGB/oi) {
                printf("TRUE: %s\n", $1);
                ($dx = $1) =~s/,//g;
}
```

It is printing

`DX                   93,132 GB  --         2,145 GB   16840176    16835553.`

But is not entering the 2nd regular expression. I have checked the regular expression and cannot see any errors. Could anyone advise?

Thanks.

Comment: If your fields are all delimited by *multiple* spaces, you might consider using `split` instead of a regex.

Comment: Your regex is broken anyway: because `.` matches *any character* and `*` is *greedy*, it will gobble up as much as it can, including the whitespace delimiters. However this is not preventing a match, it would just affect the contents of your capture `$1`. The regex does in fact match for me when I test it on your string. I'm assuming those are multiple spaces (e.g. 19 spaces between `DX` and `93,132...`?

Comment: I still need to use a regular expression to check if the line begins with DX

Comment: You can check that the line begins with `DX` *and* use `split`: `if ($line =~ /^DX/) { my @fields = split /\s{2,}/, $line; }`

Comment: We can't duplicate this problem.  show us the output of `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $line;` so we know exactly what is in $line

Comment: @AkshaiShah You are not checking if the line begins with DX in this code. Such a check would include the `^` beginning of line anchor: `/^DX/`.

Comment: @TLP I should rephrase it to "if the line contains 'DX'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your fields are delimited by *multiple* spaces (i.e. none of the fields can contain two or more spaces in a row), I would recommend using `split` instead of a regex:

```
if ($line =~ /^DX/) {
    my @fields = split /\s{2,}/, $line;
    $fields[3] =~ s/,//g; # Strip commas from 4th field
    print $fields[3];
}

__END__
2145 GB
```

If your data is actually tab delimited, change the `split` to

```
my @fields = split /\t/, $line;
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow should work: `/--\s+(\S+)\s/`

Comment: That doesn't check if the line begins with DX

Comment: `/DX[^-]+--\s+(\S)\s/`

Comment: That still does not check if the line begins with DX.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^\s*DX.*?([\d,]+)\sGB(?!.*GB)/oi
```